# Attempting to create a Delete Function(React frontend/Rails backend)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch

I am attempting to create a delete button that when hit removes a favorite coffee shop from the users profile.  The onClick is hitting the function I want, however when I attempt to get the id for the coffee shop it comes up empty.  I tried to to do `${coffee_shop_id}` because that it was is how it shows when it gets passed but was unsuccessful, I've been trying with just `${cafe.id}` because cafe passes everything back to my delete function about the coffee shop but still no luck...

This is what I have so far..

my function

```
        handleRemove = (e) => {
          console.log(e)
          const cafe = {
              coffee_shop_name: this.state.coffee_shop_name,
              coffee_shop_image_url: this.state.coffee_shop_image_url,
              coffee_shop_phone: this.state.coffee_shop_phone,
              coffee_shop_id: this.state.coffee_shop_id,
            }
           this.props.removeFav(cafe)
          }
```

my button

```
....
  <button className="submit-removefav" onClick={(e) => {this.handleRemove(e)}}> X </button>
```

my delete

```
removeFav = (cafe) => {
    console.log(cafe)
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites/${cafe.id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.token}`
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
  }
```

below is a picture of what cafe is in my delete...
[image]

my fav controller delete

```
def destroy
        favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
        favorite.destroy
        render json: {message: "Successfully removed favorite"}
    end
```

any advice is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with the following in destroy

`favorite = Favorite.find_by(params[:coffee_shop_id])`

Comment: Sorry neither one of these provided work.